# How to configure to use gcc toolchain under Cygwin?

Tags: java, gcc, makefile, build, configure

Trying to build OpenJDK 9 under Cygwin on Windows 10. I want to use the gcc toolchain, but it is finding the Microsoft toolchain by default. Getting the following error:

`bash$ ./configure MAKE=/usr/local/bin/gmake with_freetype=C:/Users/gfalk/OpenJDK/freetype
Running generated-configure.sh
configure: Configuration created at Sat Mar 17 14:44:10 EDT 2018.
configure: configure script generated at timestamp 1496926402.
checking for basename... /usr/bin/basename
checking for bash... /usr/bin/bash
....
configure: Cannot locate a valid Visual Studio installation, checking current environment
checking for Visual Studio variables... not found
configure: Cannot locate a valid Visual Studio or Windows SDK installation on disk,
configure: nor is this script run from a Visual Studio command prompt.
configure: Try setting --with-tools-dir to the VC/bin directory within the VS installation
configure: or run "bash.exe -l" from a VS command prompt and then run configure from there.
configure: error: Cannot continue
configure exiting with result code 1`

How do I point it to the gcc toolchain?

Thanks,
Geoffrey

Answer (score 0):

According to the [OpenJDK build instructions](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/file/tip/common/doc/building.md), Microsoft Visual Studio is required for building OpenJDK.

I dimly recall trying to port the Windows support to GCC and Ming64 (for cross-compilation on Fedora), but it required non-trivial changes, and never quite finished it.